# I want to make document Viewer

Tags: documentation, text-editor, image-editor

I want to make a document viewer in Html page that views photo / txt / pdf ... and I want to edit it like to put icon on the document or make text highlight or put signature .. what is the best way ??

Answer (score 0):

You can create your document viewer application using [GroupDocs.Viewer](https://docs.groupdocs.com/display/viewerproductfamily/Home) API (available for .NET and Java). It supports viewing popular document types including TXT, PDFs, and images. In addition, you can use [GroupDocs.Annotation](https://products.groupdocs.com/annotation) and [GroupDocs.Signature](https://products.groupdocs.com/signature) to annotate (highlight text) and sign the documents respectively.

*Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.*